# What is the 'did-' event prefix in electron's events about?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, naming-conventions

I've started to learn electron and it immediately struck me with its unusual naming convention for events. Some of them are named with the `did-` prefix like `did-fail-load` whereas others like `crashed` are named in the past.

Is there something I'm missing about the `did-` prefix or is it simply lack of consistency? Why is it not `did-crash` or `failed-load` etc? This is really confusing.

Comment: only someone from the Electron team could answer this. there's no obvious reason why it needed to be this way

Comment: I figured it was about granular control – "before-event", "event", "did-event". There is no "will-crash" . . . ;-)